# How can I restrict values in object data properties?

Tags: python

RMB - Edit Source on lattice data properties
[image]
how can I set min/max for this values? (min=2, max = 20)
Even if I need to change/add code to blender core .py file.

Comment: The code is from the UI. The changes you seek are in the property definitions of `bpy.types.Lattice` which AFAIK is not in some _"core"_  py file.  It would be handy to adjust this from UI, akin to changing text for buttons. My take would be to define your own `bpy.types.Lattice.foo = bpy.props.IntVectorProperty()`  which gets and sets using  the target property.

Comment: can you give me real example code what I need to add? sorry for the dumb question

Comment: Do exactly as in other answer, use `update` or in this case would go `get` and `set` _ege_ In the getter `return min(0, max(20, self.another_prop` and in the setter for "foo" `self.another_prop = value` Apologies, re other Q & A as missed the change to put props, other than booleans,  in menus.